# Repeating code, make function, but keep variables global?

Tags: php, function, variables

```
    while(strcasecmp(trim($l),"end")!=0 && $pos<count($getjkl))
    {
        $pieces = preg_split("/[\s]+/",trim($l));
        if(substr($pieces[0],0,1)!="#" && count($pieces)>1)
        {
            if(file_exists($getprj."/mat/".str_replace("\\", "/",$pieces[1])))
            {
                $found = false;
                for($j=0; $j<count($compilefiles); $j++)
                {
                    if(strcasecmp($compilefiles[$j][2],"mat\\".$pieces[1])==0)
                        $found=true;
                }
                if($found==false)
                {
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][0] = $fileoffset;
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][1] = filesize($getprj."/mat/".str_replace("\\", "/",$pieces[1]));
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][2] = "mat\\".$pieces[1];
                    $fileoffset = $fileoffset + $compilefiles[$numfiles][1];
                    $numfiles++;
                }
            }
            else if(file_exists($getprj."/3do/mat/".str_replace("\\", "/",$pieces[1])))
            {
                $found = false;
                for($j=0; $j<count($compilefiles); $j++)
                {
                    if(strcasecmp($compilefiles[$j][2],"3do\\mat\\".$pieces[1])==0)
                        $found=true;
                }
                if($found==false)
                {
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][0] = $fileoffset;
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][1] = filesize($getprj."/3do/mat/".str_replace("\\", "/",$pieces[1]));
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][2] = "3do\\mat\\".$pieces[1];
                    $fileoffset = $fileoffset + $compilefiles[$numfiles][1];
                    $numfiles++;
                }
            }
        }
        $l=$getjkl[$pos];
        $pos++;
    }
```

This here is a piece of code where I read a file and check if the listed files in there exist. Well, I actually read the file like this:

```
$getjkl = preg_split("/\R/",file_get_contents($levelfile));
```

and then step through it line by line. This block is repeated 10 times with slight differences for different file types. I then realize that I'll have to go through some file types a few more times because more file names appear later on. But instead of repeating this code, I thought I could just call this code block several times. So I do something like this:

```
    while(strcasecmp(trim($l),"end")!=0 && $pos<count($getjkl))
    {
        $pieces = preg_split("/[\s]+/",trim($l));
        if(substr($pieces[0],0,1)!="#" && count($pieces)>1)
        {
            GetMats($getprj,$pieces,$compilefiles,$numfiles,$fileoffset);
        }
        $l=$getjkl[$pos];
        $pos++;
    }
function GetMats(&$getprj,&$pieces,&$compilefiles,&$numfiles,&$fileoffset)
{
            if(file_exists($getprj."/mat/".str_replace("\\", "/",$pieces[1])))
            {
                $found = false;
                for($j=0; $j<count($compilefiles); $j++)
                {
                    if(strcasecmp($compilefiles[$j][2],"mat\\".$pieces[1])==0)
                        $found=true;
                }
                if($found==false)
                {
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][0] = $fileoffset;
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][1] = filesize($getprj."/mat/".str_replace("\\", "/",$pieces[1]));
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][2] = "mat\\".$pieces[1];
                    $fileoffset = $fileoffset + $compilefiles[$numfiles][1];
                    $numfiles++;
                }
            }
            else if(file_exists($getprj."/3do/mat/".str_replace("\\", "/",$pieces[1])))
            {
                $found = false;
                for($j=0; $j<count($compilefiles); $j++)
                {
                    if(strcasecmp($compilefiles[$j][2],"3do\\mat\\".$pieces[1])==0)
                        $found=true;
                }
                if($found==false)
                {
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][0] = $fileoffset;
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][1] = filesize($getprj."/3do/mat/".str_replace("\\", "/",$pieces[1]));
                    $compilefiles[$numfiles][2] = "3do\\mat\\".$pieces[1];
                    $fileoffset = $fileoffset + $compilefiles[$numfiles][1];
                    $numfiles++;
                }
            }

}
```

Took me a while to figure out that the variables don't automatically follow and get changed in a function unless I `&`reference them. However, after doing this to two code blocks, it seems to slow down extra much so that I hit the 30 second execution limit. Are functions really that much more expensive? And what would be the best way to call back to repeating code while still retaining the arrays and counters?

```
$getprj = string = folder
$pieces = array
$compilefiles = array (set a ways back)
$numfiles = int ( = 0 from the start) (counter)
$fileoffset = int ( = 0 from the start) (counter)
```

Comment: The beauty of functions is that they can `return` stuff. You don't have to pass by reference. You can pass in the variables and then return them as an array. I am not that familiar with the technicalities, but that should speed up execution.You could also use [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) but it is discouraged.

Comment: @Pyromonk Ok, `return`ing arrays did seem to speed things up, but one still has to send a copy of `$compilefiles` in order to check that we haven't collected that file before. Also, couldn't quite grasp it properly so `$fileoffset` and `$numfiles` had to step outside of the function and only increment if the function had a file(size) to give.